# Eclipse + WindowBuilder, swing runtime resizing and positioning

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, windowbuilder

I'm using eclipse with windowBuilder plugin. I'm facing a serious problem in the swing layout. In netbeans the default layout of swing is "free design" layout. But in eclipse the default swing layout is flowtype layout. When I add components like jbuttons or jtextfields into the panel and I'm not able resize the components in the panel. If I choose coordinate type layout the components stick to correct coordinate and wont adjust its position when we resize the window. In netbeans we enjoys the facilities like Horizontal and vertical resizing gap, while in windowbuilder i could not find them for positioning components in the jpanel. Is there any layout like "free design layout" in windowbuilder so that I can enjoy the flexibility I get in netbeans GUI designing?

Comment: *"Is there any layout like "free design layout" in windowbuilder so that I can enjoy the flexibility I get in netbeans GUI designing?"*  If by 'flexibility' you mean 'bugs' then yes there is a way, but [learn how to use layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (with layout constraints & padding and borders).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean on `GroupLayout`, the answer is: YES. But you must be aware that "flexibility", as you are calling that...costs. It produces "messed up" code, which is also hard to maintain. Also, using GUI designers, you will never fully understand `swing`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution GroupLayout

```
 //constructter 
 public AddProduct() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 539, 362);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            //change content pane layout
            contentPane.setLayout(new GroupLayout(contentPane));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
        }
```